# How to enable laptop lid suspend using alternative window manager in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, laptop, desktop-environments

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Carbon X1.  Suspend on lid closure works fine in the Gnome desktop, but I am running Fvwm, and it doesn't work there.  In the past I could get around this by borrowing Xfce power manager within Fvwm, but this is no longer working either.  Is there a way to enable recognition of lid closure events that works independently of which window manager you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if `pm-utils` is installed, else install it with `sudo apt install pm-utils`
2. Create a backup of your login configuration file `sudo cp /etc/systemd/logind.conf  /etc/systemd/logind.conf.back`
3. Open `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` with root privilege with your favourite editor
4. Un-comment the following lines `HandleSuspendKey=suspend`, `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and `HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend` and save the file
5. Reboot the system

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Arijit, I forgot about pm-utils.  That solves one problem but creates another: previously when I suspended at the command line, my network remained intact, but now with pm-utils it is taken down and I have to restart it.  (NetworkManager does not work properly on my system due to some complications).   I suppose there are some scripts where one can control this behavior, but I don't know where to find them.

Comment: and just installing pm-utils has changed the behavior of my system.  I removed it and still the laptop is suspending with lid closure, even though logind.conf is the same as I had before.  And network being removed each time.

Comment: In fact systemd/logind.conf is no longer having any effect; something else is controlling the suspend behavior now.

Comment: I have to look into it further, hope to come up with the solution. Meanwhile, does 'sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service' 
command work? Please check. Also, which driver is your network card using? Is that working well? Else, try reinstalling that too.

Comment: Actually everything works better if I just turn off NetworkManager altogether, which I have now done.  I found that in addition to changing /etc/systemd/logind.conf, I also had to do systemctl mask sleep.target in order to go back to no suspend on lid close.  systemd is a nightmare, and so is NetworkManager, if you try to use any other window manager than gnome.